# OpCode.Call to Generic Method in different assembly using raw IL

Tags: c#, generics, .net-assembly, cil, reflection.emit

I want to call a generic method using raw IL instructions. In order to learn how to do that I am using Reflection.Emit and experimenting with a dynamic assembly.

The method which I want to make a call is the following:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Method1<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassLibrary1.Class1.Method1<T>()");
    }
}
```

These are the instructions I am using

```
 byte[] ilCodes = new byte[7];
        ilCodes[0] = (byte)OpCodes.Ldarg_0.Value;
        ilCodes[1] = (byte)OpCodes.Call.Value;
        ilCodes[2] = (byte)(token & 0xFF);
        ilCodes[3] = (byte)(token >> 8 & 0xFF);
        ilCodes[4] = (byte)(token >> 16 & 0xFF);
        ilCodes[5] = (byte)(token >> 24 & 0xFF);
        ilCodes[6] = (byte)0x2A;
```

This method resides in a diferent assembly and the token you see up there is obtained like this:

```
int token = moduleBuilder.GetMethodToken(typeof(ClassLibrary1.Class1).GetMethod("Method1").GetGenericMethodDefinition()).Token;
```

I am setting the bytes with [MethodBuilder.CreateMethodBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.methodbuilder.createmethodbody(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
Now after I set the method body with those bytes, create the assembly and call its method, it fails. When I inspect the generated code in Reflector it shows me that the method call is lacking the generic parameter

```
    .method public hidebysig instance void Method1<T>() cil managed {
.maxstack 1
L_0000: ldarg.0 
L_0001: call instance void [ClassLibrary1]ClassLibrary1.Class1::Method1() <-- this should contain Method1<!!T>()
L_0006: ret }
```

How can I generate that  parameter reference in order for this to work? I know how to do it with [ILGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator(v=vs.110).aspx) but to this project its mandatory to do it with raw instructions.

Thank you.

**EDIT: This is what ILDASM shows me** (as @Lasse suggested)

```
.method /*06000001*/ public hidebysig instance void 
        Method1<T>() cil managed
// SIG: 30 01 00 01
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  1
  IL_0000:  /* 02   |                  */ ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  /* 28   | (2B)000001       */ call       instance void [ClassLibrary1/*23000002*/]ClassLibrary1.Class1/*01000002*/::Method1<!!0>() /* 2B000001 */
  IL_0006:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
} // end of method Class1::Method1
```

Comment: Have you tried using ILGenerator and then just inspecting the output?

Comment: @Lasse yes, that was how I found out that missing <!!T> parameter :)

Comment: What about ILDasm? Write the method as you would normally in C#, then disassemble the assembly and see which opcodes and tokens are used then.

Comment: @Lasse, good idea, let me check it out...

Comment: "to this project its mandatory to do it with raw instructions" Who the hell decided that?

Comment: and why does it have to be raw instructions? There should be very good reasons for avoiding the tools built into the framework, even though they are not optimal, they are heaps better than outputting bytes.

Comment: It has to do with dynamic code rewriting at runtime. In fact I just want the bytes, it will not work if it is done with ILGenerator because the tokens that ILGenerator creates are relative to the module of the dynamic generated assembly.

Comment: Your IL from ILDASM is different from what you shown earlier...

Comment: @leppie I was creating an instance of the target class...I already fixed it. Thanks for noticing it :)

Comment: As you can see, it makes a big difference :) I assume you doing this for IL rewriting profiler, so why not use native API's in that case (like everyone else does)? Edit: It is still different. Now you calling it recursively from what I can see. Some details are a miss...

Comment: @leppie no it's not different nor recursive. It's just calling the generic method that has the same name but from a different assembly. Native API's use raw bytes so there's no difference also from what I'm doing. The problem here has to do with the function token that is returning from GetMethodToken. If I call via reflection the GetMethodTokenInternal internal method from Modulebuilder it is fine because it has a useMethodDef parameter that can be set to false thus returning the correct method token.

Comment: @leppie ...Comments on the  source code for GetMethodTokenInternal say exactly that.

Comment: @RicardoBarbosa: I see :)

Comment: @RicardoBarbosa: I think you are looking for `typeof(Class1).GetMethod("Method1").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object))` You will have to figure out though how you supply the type for `T` (I just used `typeof(object)` in my example). In fact the call `GetGenericMethodDefinition()` is redundant, but either way you end up with an 'open method' that cannot be called if you dont specify the generic type argument with `MakeGenericMethod()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `ILGenerator` can do this, I looked at [what it does](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/modulebuilder.cs,1322335044bf9d6f). What I figured out is that you need a `MethodSpec` token, but to get that, you will need to call several internal methods, just like the above linked code (I used [ExposedObject](https://github.com/Cognifide/ExposedObject) to make some of the reflection simpler):

```
int token = moduleBuilder.GetMethodToken(typeof(Class1).GetMethod("Method1")).Token;

SignatureHelper sigHelper = Exposed.From(typeof(SignatureHelper))
    .GetMethodSpecSigHelper(moduleBuilder, new Type[] { typeParameter });

var getSignatureParameters = new object[] { 0 };
byte[] bytes = (byte[])typeof(SignatureHelper).GetMethod(
    "InternalGetSignature", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Invoke(sigHelper, getSignatureParameters);

int length = (int)getSignatureParameters[0];

var runtimeModule = Exposed.From(moduleBuilder).GetNativeHandle();

token = (int)typeof(TypeBuilder)
    .GetMethod("DefineMethodSpec", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { runtimeModule, token, bytes, length });
```

Here, `typeParameter` is the `GenericTypeParameterBuilder` returned from `DefineGenericParameters`. Using this code, Reflector shows the following IL, which I believe is what you wanted (except that I made `Method1` static and so replaced `ldarg.0` with `nop`):

```
.method privatescope static void M2<U>() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 16
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: call void [ClassLibrary1]Class1::Method1<!!U>()
    L_0006: ret 
}
```

Comment: That's exactly that @svick generic methods need MethodSpec tokens and not MethodRef. I already discovered that also a couple of days ago, just like you did, sniffing around  the clr code. I am accepting your excelent answer, but I want to  thank also to all the people involved who all  gave excelent contributions in helping me finding this out. This was a tough one :)

Answer (score 2):

First off, be sure that you use the correct `call` or `callvirt`. It's usually best to use `callvirt` if you have an reference type, because it will also implicitly add a null check - but apart from that, if you're using any type inheritance, your PEVerify will fail and it will therefore result in undefined behavior.

Next, I'd have to add that finding the correct method to call is usually pretty nasty.

You probably want to avoid using `MakeGenericMethod` because that means you also need to use `GetMethod`, which might give you the incorrect overload. Implementing your own overload resolution rules that reflect .NET is possible, but pretty difficult (I have a post on SO somewhere about that that includes the solution).

The easiest way to go is to make generic types and call methods. Basically you can do that like this:

```
Type myType = typeof(MyType<>).MakeGenericType(someType);
```

That will give you a wrapper containing a generic type for the TypeBuilder you're using. (Assuming `someType` is a TypeBuilder if I understand your question correctly).

Next, you need to get the correct method. Again, this is nasty, since the wrapper doesn't have the right methods yet -- after all, we're still building the type. TypeBuilder has a static method for that, `GetMethod` that allows you to use the method in the generic definition to lookup the method in your newly brew generic thing. For example:

```
var baseMethod = 
    TypeBuilder.GetMethod(typeof(IEquatable<>).MakeGenericType(builder)), 
    typeof(IEquatable<>).GetMethod("Equals" /* add constraints */));
```

Two things to note when you go down this path:

1. Save your assemblies to disk, and use PEVerify for everything. **Even if it runs!** It'll save you a ton of trouble.
2. You might want to consider simply casting and using `object` or a normal non-generic interface. As long as you're not using value types, the IL will only JIT the code once, so there is usually no performance penalty. (If you're interested, I have a question about this on SO)